# Flow Formula Field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

How can I update a picklist status value to Inactive when a record has passed 31 days After Job End date?

I have a scheduled flow setup on weekly basis and it should check all Active records and update their Status to inactive if the Job End Date has passed 31 days. When I run a debug, it updates incorrect jobs to inactive
The Flow should only check records that have end date passed 31 days

`Job_End_Date__c` greater or equal `EndDatePassed` (contains below formula)

Formula field-> `{!$Record._Job_End_Date__c} + 30`

Can someone advise please?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including av[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your verbal description isn't enough to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: it looks like you are comparing `job end date` to `job end date + 30` - this can never be true. You need to compare today's date to `job end date + 30`

Comment: Interesting, would the formula look something like below? TODAY() + (-1) + {!$Record._Job_End_Date__c} + 30. Would that Today part be in the formula itself or a filter in Get Records which is set after the starts?

Comment: Not sure how to compare the end date with today, it should pick up records from before or after today  that finished 30 days after the Job.                                 
 @cropredy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flow builder the current date is stored in the global variable [`{!$Flow.CurrentDate}`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_resources_system_variables.htm&type=5), so you could define a formula `ThirtyOneDaysAgo` as `{!$Flow.CurrentDate} - 31`, then in Get Records element the conditions will be:

1. `Job_End_Date__c` Less Than or Equal `ThirtyOneDaysAgo`
2. `Status__c` Equals Active.

Another way to achieve this would be creating a Boolean formula field (i.e. `Should_Be_Inactive__c`) on that object defined as:

```
TODAY() >= Job_End_Date__c + 31 && ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Active')
```

Then in flow you could just query every record with `Should_Be_Inactive__c` = TRUE

Comment: this is very helpful - thanks a lot Ruben !

Comment: @Flownewbie You're welcome. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.